# Programmatically save an Excel file using the file name from a textbox

Tags: c#, excel

Can you help me improve the code. I'm getting an error. Textbox text: "C:\Users\ASUS NBK\Desktop\csharptest.xls"

```
string fileName = textBox9.Text;
        xlWorkBook.SaveAs(fileName , Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();
```

It works well when I put the it like this:

```
 xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\\Users\\ASUS NBK\\Desktop\\csharptest.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
        xlApp.Quit();
```

Comment: I just edited it. I want to save the file with the path and filename from the textbox input.

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in WindowsFormsApplication1.exe